# TILE_DIM and BLOCK_ROWS could not be resolved

Tags: cuda

i try to implement this

```
__global__ void transposeNaive(float *odata, const float *idata)
{
  int x = blockIdx.x * TILE_DIM + threadIdx.x;
  int y = blockIdx.y * TILE_DIM + threadIdx.y;
  int width = gridDim.x * TILE_DIM;

  for (int j = 0; j < TILE_DIM; j+= BLOCK_ROWS)
    odata[x*width + (y+j)] = idata[(y+j)*width + x];
}
```

why i get this error? What is going wrong here? Why i get this error?

Comment: This question is like "fill the gap with the proper words!" Where did you have retrieved this kernel?

Answer (score 1):

Your question has to do with C and C++, not CUDA.

In C or C++, if I have a statement like this:

```
int x = 5 * TESTVAL;
```

Then somewhere else in my code preceding this statement I need something like:

```
#define TESTVAL 7
```

or

```
int TESTVAL = 7;
```

If I don't have anything in my code that defines what `TESTVAL` is, the compiler will give an error.  You don't need statements that define what things like `blockIdx.x` and `threadIdx.x` are, because those are built-ins that the CUDA device code compiler knows how to handle.

You need something in your code somewhere that defines what `TILE_DIM` and `BLOCK_ROWS` are.